# Crytal Reports on Visual Studio 2010 note showing all column names

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, crystal-reports

I´ve tried looking around stackoverflow and google and no luck...

The problem is that I´ve just installed Crytal Reports, and it seems to have installed correctly, howveer, when i try to open a table in a database, it loads the table but it´s missing one column...which in this case is the most important column, since it includes date and time of an event...

Does anyone know how i could solve this? or a work around?

Thank you very much! all help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the datatype of the column? I have found certain datatypes (such as Text, which is different from varchar2, the datatype normally used for character data in Oracle) to be poorly supported by Crystal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this thread](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1581368) on SAP's forums, it appears as though this is a known issue using Crystal Reports with Oracle Timestamp columns. The recommended solution is to access the Oracle database with Crystal's native Oracle driver (rather than OLE DB, ODBC, etc).